# YouTube Embed Player: Thumbnails are pixelated for small player, but look fine for large player

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am simply using the default YouTube embed code (generated by YouTube) to display videos on my website. With the layout that uses a fairly narrow width (320px wide) for the YouTube player, the video thumbnail is a very low quality that is visibly pixelated. However, with the layout that uses a fairly wide width (1100px wide) for the YouTube player, the video thumbnail is the high resolution version and looks great.

Here are two links that compare the different thumbnails:

- Narrow, low quality thumbnail: http://slackrbike0.wpengine.com/
- Wide, high quality thumbnail: http://slackrbike0.wpengine.com/?cat=1

Has anyone run into this issue where the thumbnail quality is crap on smaller embedded videos? And has anyone come up with a fix? Or do I have to wait for YouTube to fix it on their end?

Here is the embed code I am using, again the default generated by YouTube:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NoIKoTs1s9Y" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically YT send multiple dimension of thumbnail, if ur container is smaller that 321px then the smallest thumbnail will get loaded that is `"width": 120,"height": 90`. this is root-cause of this issue.

Element with `width <= 320px` having issue of bury thumbnail.

I have found a workaround by setting iframe width with `min-width:321px` that will force to load higher dimension thumbnail

```
iframe {
    min-width:321px;
}
```

I hope this will helpfull for you.

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of trial and error, I found that increasing the height attribute in the iframe tag by 1 forced the YouTube player to use a higher resolution thumbnail. Hope this saves you some time if you run into a similar issue...